# using two jquery frameworks

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jquery 1.2.6 with the seperate jquery tabs framework. I also need to use the 1.3.2 jquery  sortable & resizable. I need to make those two to work.

how do i manage these two frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *much* **much** better off bringing everything on the same platform (and unless there's a reason, why not jQuery 1.4.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.1?).

Most likely upgrading any plugins that are currently keeping you on 1.2.6 isn't that difficult, if there's any work to do at all...trust me, it's a lot less work than debugging issues from 2 versions of jQuery trying to battle it out...it's just not designed to do this.

Comment: problem is, i'm relying on the 1.2.6's tabs with the close button.

Comment: @Martin - You can do this still with the latest tabs, here's an example: http://andrew.io/weblog/2010/01/a-close-button-for-jquery-ui-tabs/  There's a demo available here, give it a look: http://andrew.io/playpen/ui.tabs.closable/demo/

Comment: Nick is right. Do ANYTHING you can to avoid using two different platforms!

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll try to make a work around first. I don't have time to adjust all frameworks into one. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: I highly doubt upgrading to jQuery 1.4.2 and (if needed) jQuery UI 1.8.1 would break your site. Upgrade now and save yourself some headache. Not only would 2 different versions of jQuery create extremely unnecessary overhead, but you're using much older versions to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "jQuery tabs framework", but jQuery-UI has a nice "tabs" plugin that works with the latest jQuery.
Anyway, if you **have** to use both versions, maybe something like this might work (probably not, but might be worth a shot) => [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you even tried to see if the tabs stuff works with jQuery 1.3?  Or just go ahead and try it with 1.4, there's been a lot of improvements.

jQuery releases are almost completely backwards compatible (for most practical purposes), and I've never had any issues updating.
 I'm using a bunch of old plugins designed for 1.2.x running on 1.4.2 no problem.